# Integrating Listview and search

Tags: android

Im having hard time integrating search in a custom listview. I have a listview using layout.xml and adapter then when I added search in my existing listview the search is working but the layout in not show in the list.Kindly click here for the file
[Android Zip Click here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/dd0h8613b11vutr/SearchView.zip?dl=0).

Main Activity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{
EditText search;
ListView listview;
ArrayList<Person> list=new ArrayList<Person>();
ArrayList<Person> source=new ArrayList<Person>();
ArrayAdapter<Person> adapter;

AlertDialog.Builder builder;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
//
this.search=(EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        this.listview=(ListView) this.findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        //populate source

        //list.add(new Person(R.drawable.melvin,"Melvin ","PhD Educational Management"));
        source.add(new Person(R.drawable.dennis,"Dennis ","Master in Information Technology"));
        source.add(new Person(R.drawable.jonathan,"Jonathan ","PhD in Technological Management"));
        source.add(new Person(R.drawable.bell,"Bell ","MS Information Technology"));
        source.add(new Person(R.drawable.jennifer,"Jennifer ","PhD Technological Management"));
        source.add(new Person(R.drawable.gian,"Gian","MS Information Technology"));
        //delegatethe list to the adapter
        adapter=new ArrayAdapter<Person>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,list);
        //delegate the  adapter to the listview
        this.listview.setAdapter(adapter);
        //delegate a key watcher
        this.search.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1,
                    int arg2, int arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1,
                    int arg2, int arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                //clear the listview
                list.clear();
                //get match
                String regex=arg0.toString();
                Pattern p=Pattern.compile(regex);
                for(int i=0;i<source.size();i++){
                    Matcher m=p.matcher((CharSequence) list.get(i));
                    while(m.find()){
                        list.add(source.get(i));
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                }
            }

        });
    }
```

Adapter
   package com.example.searchlist;

public class ItemAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

```
Context context;
ArrayList<Person> list;
LayoutInflater inflater;

public ItemAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Person> list) {
    super();
    this.context = context;
    this.list = list;
    this.inflater=LayoutInflater.from(context);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return list.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return list.get(arg0);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return arg0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int arg0, View arg1, ViewGroup arg2) {
    PersonHandler handler =null;
    if(arg1==null){
        arg1=inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_layout, null);
        handler=new PersonHandler();
        handler.iv=(ImageView) arg1.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        handler.name=(TextView) arg1.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        handler.course=(TextView) arg1.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        arg1.setTag(handler);
    }
    else handler=(PersonHandler) arg1.getTag();

    handler.iv.setImageResource(list.get(arg0).getImg());
    handler.name.setText(list.get(arg0).getName());
    handler.course.setText(list.get(arg0).getCourse());

    return arg1;
}
static class PersonHandler{
    ImageView iv;
    TextView name, course;
}
}
```

layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="#0000ff" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:text="Small Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textColor="#ff0000" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#4682b4"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="SEARCH"
    android:padding="10dp" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:background="#fafad2" >

</ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "the layout in not show in the list"?

Comment: i have layout xml integrated in my listview instead of plain text i added photo on it. so i used adapter to link it but it has an error

Comment: If you mean you're getting an error when using `ItemAdapter`, you'll need to tell us exactly what it is.

Comment: ill just show it to you what im uploading

Comment: this is the images [https://www.dropbox.com/s/hhgfgx55vdu0k3s/Untitled.png?dl=0] What I want to do is when search names on search box which is listed on my listview the only thing will show is the name photo course which is already in the listview.

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean. Are you saying that the searched list should have the photo too? The code you've posted isn't actually using `ItemAdapter` anywhere, so the first image in that screenshot doesn't really match up with the given code.

Comment: i has itemadapter after main code. This is the whole file[https://www.dropbox.com/s/dd0h8613b11vutr/SearchView.zip?dl=0&m=] so that you willnot be confuse.

Comment: Yeah, you've got that all of that in the question (except the `Person` class, which is fine). What I'm saying is that you're not actually using `ItemAdapter` anywhere. You're using a plain old `ArrayAdapter` in `MainActivity` – `ArrayAdapter<Person> adapter;`. An `ArrayAdapter` will only display a single text value for each item. It doesn't handle multiple `TextView`s, or `ImageView`s at all, by default, so I don't know what that first image in your screenshot is showing.

Comment: ah the screen shot is 2 different app.one for the the view and one for search. I just wanted to show how the project work. that when you type a name in search instead of plain name will show up in listview but it has name and course on it and a picture.Also we are using traditional editor the eclipse

Comment: OK, then, if I'm understanding you correctly, your problem is just that you're not actually using your `ItemAdapter` class. You need to replace the `ArrayAdapter` in `MainActivity` with `ItemAdapter`.

Comment: Yes,im having hardtime converting that one so that search will populate in list

Comment: What problems are you having, exactly? Please be specific.

Comment: when you type a name in search instead of plain name will show up in listview but it has name and course on it and a picture.output [dropbox.com/s/hhgfgx55vdu0k3s/Untitled.png?dl=0] this the file [dropbox.com/s/dd0h8613b11vutr/SearchView.zip?dl=0&m=]

Comment: As I've said, you're not using `ItemAdapter` in `MainActivity`. You need to use `ItemAdapter` instead of `ArrayAdapter`. If you're having problems changing `ArrayAdapter` to `ItemAdapter` in `MainActivity`, then that's what you need to explain.

Comment: ArrayList<Person> list=new ArrayList<Person>();ArrayList<Person> source=new ArrayList<Person>();
  //ArrayAdapter<Person> adapter;
  ItemAdapter adapter;